# Compute mse after keras model. Prediction looks to be wrong--updated need to reshape array first

Tags: python-3.x, keras

So I would like to compute `R2 = 1 - residual_ss/y_ss` after keras. I used the prediction `model.predict()` to compute `residual_ss`. However, the `residual_ss` is much larger than `y_ss` which results in a negative `R2`. Since `residual_ss = n*mse` and `mse` is also the loss function, the code shows the computation for `mse` after the model:

```py
import keras
keras.__version__
from keras.datasets import boston_housing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

(train_data, train_targets), (test_data, test_targets) =  boston_housing.load_data()
mean = train_data.mean(axis=0)
train_data -= mean
std = train_data.std(axis=0)
train_data /= std

test_data -= mean
test_data /= std

from keras import models
from keras import layers

def build_model():
    # Because we will need to instantiate
    # the same model multiple times,
    # we use a function to construct it.
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu',
                           input_shape=(train_data.shape[1],)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
    return model

model=build_model()
model.fit(train_data,  train_targets, epochs=200, batch_size=32)

#try to get mse
y_pred = model.predict(train_data)
mse=np.mean((train_targets-y_pred)*(train_targets-y_pred))
print(mse)
```

Here is last 3 epochs and the `mse` in the end

```
Epoch 198/200
404/404 [=======] - 0s 17us/step - loss: 3.4695 - mean_absolute_error: 1.3338
Epoch 199/200
404/404 [=======] - 0s 22us/step - loss: 3.5412 - mean_absolute_error: 1.3260
Epoch 200/200
404/404 [=======] - 0s 20us/step - loss: 3.2775 - mean_absolute_error: 1.2858
162.25934358457062
```

I only use `train_data` and `train_targets` here. Why I got a `mse` not even close to the loss (`mse`) reported in each epoch? So the prediction is not close to the target. Please help.

Comment: Could you add the full traceback ?

Comment: Do you mean the output? I added last 3 epochs and the mse in my post. By the way, the code should be ready to run.

Comment: try to use a sigmode activation function, I had the same issue before. relu function hard to fit regression problem.